# Servlet Security transport-guarantee "CONFIDENTIAL" does not display the requested page after redirect

Tags: tomcat, servlets, web.xml

I was just trying the Servlet Security Mechanism. I have used `<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>` in my web.xml with "BASIC" authentication. When the constrained resource is accessed, after the redirect the page is not displayed.Following are my code snippets

tomcat-users.xml

```
<role rolename="Admin"/>
<role rolename="Member"/>
<role rolename="Guest"/>
<user username="Annie" password="admin" roles="Admin, Member, Guest"/>
<user username="Diane" password="coder" roles="Member, Guest"/>
<user username="Ted" password="newbie" roles="Guest"/>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app version="3.0">
  <display-name>SecurityApp</display-name>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>BeerAppServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.examples.servlets.BeerAppServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>BeerAppServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Beer/AddRecipe</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

    <security-role>
    <role-name>Admin</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>Member</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>Guest</role-name>
  </security-role>

  <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Update</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/Beer/AddRecipe/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>Admin</role-name>
      <role-name>Member</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>

    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
 </security-constraint>

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  </login-config>

</web-app>
```

My Servlet class is as follows

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        writer.println("<h3> Welcome to Beer Application Site</h3>");

    }
```

When i access my application as follows

```
http://localhost:8083/SecurityApp/Beer/AddRecipe
```

The re-direct is done and the above mentioned url changes to

```
https://localhost:8553/SecurityApp/Beer/AddRecipe
```

and no page is displayed, instead the browser displays as follows

The connection was reset
The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

I expect the page should be displayed with  Welcome to Beer Application Site.
I am using tomcat apache-tomcat-7.0.47
My re-direct port in server.xml is

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8083" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8553"/>
```

Can anyone please let me know what is wrong here or if i am missing any configurations that needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

After going through the Tomcat Documentation i came to know that SSL needs to be enabled in server.xml of tomcat

As per the documentation to enable SSL Configuration first we need to generate .keystore file.

These are the steps provided in tomcat documentation

To install and configure SSL support on Tomcat, you need to follow these simple steps.

Create a keystore file to store the server's private key and self-signed certificate by executing the following command:

Windows:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
```

Since i have a windows system, the following are the steps i have done to generate the .keystore file

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin>keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
Enter keystore password:
Re-enter new password:
What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]:  AvinashReddy
What is the name of your organizational unit?
  [Unknown]:  Organization Name
What is the name of your organization?
  [Unknown]:  Organization Name
What is the name of your City or Locality?
  [Unknown]:  Hyderabad
What is the name of your State or Province?
  [Unknown]:  AndhraPradesh
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
  [Unknown]:  AP
Is CN=AvinashReddy, OU=Organization Name, O=Organization Name, L=Hyderabad, ST=AndhraPradesh, C=AP correct?
  [no]: yes

  Enter key password for <tomcat>
        (RETURN if same as keystore password):
```

As per the documentation i have used the password " changeit "(all lower case) and in the last step i have just pressed "Enter" key so it used the same password that was keyed when the following question "Enter keystore password" was asked while the generation of .keytstore file

And i have changed the server.xml in tomcat as follows

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8083" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8553"/

  <Connector port="8553" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
               keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit" />

<Connector port="8010" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8553"/>
```

The default port for redirect in tomcat is 8443, since i had 2 instances of tomcat running on my system i have changed the redirect port from 8443 to 8553.

After the changes i restarted my tomcat and could access the constrained resource.

i have typed

```
http://localhost:8083/SecurityApp/Beer/AddRecipe
```

then this was redirected to

```
https://localhost:8553/SecurityApp/Beer/AddRecipe
```

Since i have used "BASIC" authentication mechanism i was prompted for user name and password. After providing the credentials i was able to see my page as follows

"Welcome to Beer Application Site"

The following is the link for configuring SSL provided by tomcat

```
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Configuration
```